# Smoother outlines of`RegionFunction` in `ContourPlot`

Tags: plotting

I'm looking to make a publication-quality plot of a Dirichlet distribution and trying to figure out how to get rid of jaggy edges along the region function in the `ContourPlot`. Cranking up `PlotPoints` to 175 takes 20 seconds but the artifacts remain. `RegionPlot` on other hand is able to plot the region nicely with default parameters. Any tips?

```
{vec1, vec2} = Orthogonalize@NullSpace[{{1, 1, 1}}];
transformed = vec1 z1 + vec2 z2 + {1/3, 1/3, 1/3};
(*Refine[PDF[DirichletDistribution[{1/2,1/2,1/2}],{x,y}],x>0&&y>0&&1-\
x-y>0]*)
pdf[x_, y_] = 1/(2 \[Pi] Sqrt[x (1 - x - y) y]); 
pdf2[z1_, z2_] = 
  pdf[x, y] /. Thread[{x, y} -> Most[transformed]] // Simplify;
regionFunc[z1_, z2_] = And @@ Thread[0 <= transformed <= 1];
RegionPlot[
 regionFunc[z1, z2], {z1, -(1/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2]}, {z2, -(1/Sqrt[6]),
   Sqrt[3/2] + -1/Sqrt[6]}, AspectRatio -> 1]
ContourPlot[
 pdf2[z1, z2], {z1, -(1/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2]}, {z2, -(1/Sqrt[6]), 
  Sqrt[3/2] + -1/Sqrt[6]}, AspectRatio -> 1, BoundaryStyle -> White, 
 RegionFunction -> (regionFunc[#1, #2] &), 
 PlotRange -> {pdf2[0, 0], 10}, ClippingStyle -> White, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][1 - #] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: does `RegionPlot[
 regionFunc[z1, z2], {z1, -(1/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2]}, {z2, -(1/Sqrt[6]),
   Sqrt[3/2] + -1/Sqrt[6]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 MeshFunctions -> {pdf2[#, #2] &}, Mesh -> {Range[7]}, 
 MeshShading -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][1 - #] & /@ Subdivide[7]), 
 PlotPoints -> 100, BoundaryStyle -> White]` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr VERY GOOD!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `RegionPlot` and draw the contours using the option `MeshFunctions`:

```
RegionPlot[regionFunc[z1, z2], 
 {z1, -(1/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2]}, {z2, -(1/Sqrt[6]), Sqrt[3/2] + -1/Sqrt[6]},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 MeshFunctions -> {pdf2},
 Mesh -> {Range[9]},
 MeshShading -> (ColorData[{"SolarColors", "Reverse"}] /@ Subdivide[9]),
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 BoundaryStyle -> White]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `.02 <= transformed <= 1` to clip the singular boundary.

```
{vec1, vec2} = Orthogonalize@NullSpace[{{1, 1, 1}}];
transformed = vec1 z1 + vec2 z2 + {1/3, 1/3, 1/3};
pdf[x_, y_] = 1/(2 π Sqrt[x (1 - x - y) y]);
pdf2[z1_, z2_] = 
  pdf[x, y] /. Thread[{x, y} -> Most[transformed]] // Simplify;
regionFunc[z1_, z2_] = And @@ Thread[.02 <= transformed <= 1];
ContourPlot[
 pdf2[z1, z2], {z1, -(1/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2]}, {z2, -(1/Sqrt[6]), 
  Sqrt[3/2] + -1/Sqrt[6]}, AspectRatio -> 1, BoundaryStyle -> Black, 
 RegionFunction -> (regionFunc[#1, #2] &), 
 PlotRange -> {pdf2[0, 0], 10}, ClippingStyle -> White, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][1 - #] &)]
```

[image]